# how to capture the error code or error message from psutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, psutil

I have a sample python3 code below, and want to capture what kinds of error when calling psutil functions. However after running the code below, it only prints out the `Error:  <class 'psutil.Error'>`.

How can I capture the real meaningful error message here? Thanks.

```
import psutil

pid = 12345

try:
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    p.terminate()
except psutil.Error:
    print("Error: ", psutil.Error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the error to a variable on the end of your except statement, like this:

```
import psutil

pid = 12345

try:
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    p.terminate()
except psutil.Error as error:
    stringerror = str(error)
    print ("Error: " + stringerror)
```

I've also converted the error statement variable to a string at the end so the output here is as you intended, this avoids a TypeError with concantenation.